# Proving Sherman-Morrison's formula with Einstein notation

Tags: inverse, tensor-products

As part of some homework assignments in a course in continuum mechanics, I'm trying to prove the Sherman-Morrison's formula:
$$(B_{ij}+\alpha u_iv_j)^{-1}=B_{ij}^{-1}-\frac{\alpha}{1 + \alpha v_k B_{kl}^{-1}u_l}B_{im}^{-1}u_m v_n B_{nj}^{-1} $$

using the following identity:

$$(\delta_{ij}+\alpha u_iv_j)^{-1}=\delta_{ij}-\frac{\alpha}{1 + \alpha u_k v_k}u_i v_j$$

The purpose of most of the exercises in the course this far has been to make us students comfortable with using indices with Einstein's summation convention. Although I feel a lot more comfortable with it now after working with it for two weeks than when we first started, it still confuses me at times.

My solution:

Set  $\alpha u_i = B_{ik} w_k$. This implies that $w_l=\alpha B_{li}^{-1} u_i$. The left hand side of the formula I'm trying to prove can then be written like this:

$$(B_{ij}+\alpha u_iv_j)^{-1}=(B_{ij}+B_{ik} w_k v_j)^{-1}=(B_{im}(\delta_{mj} + w_m v_j))^{-1}=B_{im}^{-1}\left(\delta_{mj} -\frac{1}{1+ w_k v_k} w_m v_j\right)=B_{ij}^{-1}-\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha B_{kn}^{-1} u_n v_k}B_{mn}^{-1} u_n v_j B_{im}^{-1}$$

This is correct except for the indices in the $B_{mn}^{-1} u_n v_j B_{im}^{-1}$-factor. Compared to the corresponding factor in the given Sherman-Morrison formula, $B_{im}^{-1}u_m v_n B_{nj}^{-1}$, $B_{mn}$ in my expression contains only dummy indices, and $v_j$ has a free index, but this should not be the case.

I would be very thankful if someone could help me find my error, and I wish you all a good day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$. The orders of the factors reverse. Other than that I think you're good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I am aware that this is the case for matrix multiplication, but I thought of $B_{im}$ as an element of a matrix, and therefore a scalar, so multiplication with it is commutative. Is this thinking wrong?

Do you think the expression for the Sherman-Morrison's formula given in the assignment, the one I'm trying to reach, is wrong then?

Comment: @FelixEriksson To invert a matrix you do not just invert each entry. (I'm sure you know this). So when you've written $(B_{ij}+\alphau_iv_j)^{-1}$ you are not being strictly accurate. You mean the inverse of the matrix, but what you've written is strictly the inverse of an element. This abuse of notation is (sort of) okay, but you have to remember that the ${}^{-1}$ really means "inverse of the matrix with these elements", and not "inverse of this scalar". So you do have to reverse the order of the two factors.

Comment: Thanks! I finally understood how to do the inversion. I'm aware that you can't just invert the elements in a matrix to get the inversion of the matrix, but my abuse of notation came from not correctly translating this knowledge to index language. What you said in your answer could be written: $(C_{ij}D_{jk})^{-1}=C_{jk}^{-1}D_{ij}^{-1}$, right? When using this everything turned out fine.